# How to mock static method that returns final class?

Tags: java, junit

I want to mock next line:

```
Bigquery bigquery = Transport.newBigQueryClient(options).build();
```

The problem here is that newBigQueryClient method returns Bulder class, which is final. This means that I cannot mock it neither with mockito or powermockito(it returns such exception: Cannot subclass final class), but I need to return something suitable to mock build method on it. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Can `BigQuery` be extended (in case of a class) or implemented (in case of an interface)?

Comment: Why don't create an instance of it and return it instead?

Comment: Its a class and its possible to extend it. @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: If I return an instance after newBigQueryClient method(Builder object), then I cannot mock it further. @aribeiro

Comment: If using powerMock is an option, this [link](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockFinal) may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion to improve your code and making it much more testable:

First of all, you do not mock a *statement* like the assignment that you gave us as an example. You mock *objects* and assign their references to variables whose type represent a super type.

Additionally, if you feel you have to mock something away, you have obviously found a dependency in your code snippet that is an important concept.

**Make this concept obvious!**

In your case, you want to get a `Bigquery` object and assign its reference to a variable. The unclear concept is that someone has to *provide* such an object.

Make this concept clear with an interface:

```
interface BigqueryProvider {
    Bigquery provide(Object options);
}
```

In your class where you also have the statement

```
Bigquery bigquery = Transport.newBigQueryClient(options).build();
```

you now add the following instance variable

```
private final BigqueryProvider bigqueryProvider;
```

and change your constructors accordingly. As I made it `final` it must be set at construction time. Of course, you must also identify the code where you call the constructors. For that you also need a default implementation:

```
final class DefaultBigqueryProvider implements BigqueryProvider {
    @Override
    public Bigquery provide(Object options) {
        return Transport.newBigQueryClient(options).build();
    }
}
```

Then change the above mentioned assignment to

```
Bigquery bigquery = bigqueryProvider.provide(options);
```

Now to the tests: In your tests, you now can provide a test implementation for the provider interface. A mocking framework can easily do that for you. You are also able to return a `Bigquery` object of your choice, being it an object of that class or of a subclass, it doesn't matter.

Your test code then instantiates your class by providing them a mocked `BigqueryProvider` which you have under full control.