# Java - Changing clock time for LocalDate & Instant

Tags: java

We use

```
LocalDate.now() and 
Instant.now()
```

in our Application. 
Working on Unit testing and would like to test few things with Future Date and Past date. We do change the System clock and testing this. Is it possible to do these kind of testing without Changing the system clock.

We have the following option.

```
LocalDate.now(Clock clock)
```

But, the problem is, we are using LocalDate.now() in so many places and hence changing the code is not an option.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your query fully, but is this what you are looking for? `  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 15);
  Date futureDate = calendar.getTime();`

Comment: Why don't you try  LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1); and LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1); to play with future date and past date

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178388/how-to-mock-static-method-that-returns-final-class/36178992#36178992) to [a question about mocking and testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178388/how-to-mock-static-method-that-returns-final-class). It does not deal with date and time, but the mechanism is the same. Unfortunately, you have to touch your code (at all those places). But in terms of quality, I think you want to improve your code, don't you?

Comment: I want Localdate.now() to return future or past date without changing the system clock.

Comment: Really, you don't want to _change_ `LocalDate`'s behavior. You want to unit-test your code that has a dependency to some date and/or time providing concepts. In fact, [you are asking for _X_ but you want to achieve _Y_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I suggest you write up your comments as an Answer.  You are correct, the OP needs to alter their existing code to make it testable despite their reluctance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an unusual desire, and while the best solution is generally to rewrite the code to be a little more testable, [people have used mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415404/fnord) to do this kind of thing. That's the kind of solution that needs to be surrounded by disclaimers on all sides, though. Friends don't let friends do this.