# use powerMock for static method in Final class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am testing class ClassToTest which internally calls static method from class B which is throwing and exception when parameter is null.
Sample code :

```
 public final class ClassToTest{
    public returnObject apply(final Optional<classC> classC, final ReturnObject returnObject){
        throwException when classC.isNull();
        throwException when returnObject.isNull();

        if(classC.isPresent()){
            try{
                ClassB.validate(classC.get(),returnObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }

        public classB{
            public static void validate(final ClassC classC, ReturnObject returnObject){
                throwException.when(classC.isNull());
                throwException.when(returnObject.isNull());
                throwException.when(classC.getReturn().isNull());
                if(syx.successful){
                    checkForNull(classC,returnObject)
                }

            private static void checkForNull(Classx classx, ReturnObject returnObject){
                throwException.when(classx.getReturn().getCollectionObject().isNull());
                throwException.when(classx.getReturn().getgetCollectionObject().getResponse().isNUll();
            }
            }
```

I cannot put the actual code here.
In the class to test I want to ignore call to the validate method using doIgnore(). I tried in following way but I am getting exception.

```
 @Mock  private ClassB classB;
 ClassB classBspy= PowerMockito.spy(classB);
 Mockito.doNothing().when(classBspy).validate(classC,returnObject);
```

I am getting following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here: (at doNothing line)
```

When debugged, testing call to validate is not completely ignored, in validate method getting exception at `throwException.when(classC.getReturn().isNull()`

Comment: Check this, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178388/how-to-mock-static-method-that-returns-final-class

Comment: spy (ied) should be valid instance, not a mock